# nested-name-specifier

Tags: c++, templates, generic-programming

I have a code like:

```
namespace mymap {
    template <class Key,template <typename T > class Allocator> myownmap {
        typedef pair<const unsigned int, Key> typename _myPair;
        typedef multimap<unsigned int, Key,less<Key> ,Allocator<_myPair> > typename _entriesType;
    }
}
```

It compiles successfully (and works) under MSVC, but gcc is complaining about invalid syntax:

```
.hpp:20: error: expected nested-name-specifier before ‘_myPair’
.hpp:20: error: two or more data types in declaration of ‘_myPair’
```

what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: did you really test THIS code with gcc? you are missing a class/struct before myownmap and "entriesPair" doesn't occur anywhere in your snippet.

Comment: Can you show us the definition of `entriesPair`?

Comment: What is `myownmap` ? is it a function or class ?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The `typename` is not needed there, and is therefore not allowed.

MSVC do not parse templates properly until they are actually used, so some errors are not found until later.

Answer (score 14):

"expected nested-name-specifier" means that after `typename` keyword you are expected to use some nested name of a template parameter, for example `typedef typename Key::iterator ...`. In your case you don't have to use `typename`.

Answer (score 7):

```
typedef pair<const unsigned int, Key> /*typename*/ _myPair;
                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^ not needed
```

See the [gcc-4.5 output here](http://www.ideone.com/EkOgQ). (it holds true for `myownmap` being `class` or function)